# Stuck in a while loop in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, while-loop

I'm very new to python so bear with me. I have this code below which I've inserted a while loop to make sure every time a name is given it checks to verify that name is in the csv and then if it isn't it gives and error and asks for a new name. My problem is that I can't seem to get out of the loop. Even with a new name that I know for a fact is in the csv it still sticks in the loop. My question is how can I get this code to run through a loop and verify the name is in there? any help would be great. I am even open to changing the entire code if there's a better way to write this.

Here's what I got:

```
import csv

full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()

with open('Report1.csv') as csvfile:
    hour_summation = {}
    read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in read_csv:
        while (' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() != full_name.strip().lower():
            print('Name is not in system')
            full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()
        if(' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() == full_name.strip().lower():
            hour_summation[row[2]] = hour_summation.get(row[2], 0) + int(float(row[3]))
print('This is {} full hours report:'.format(full_name))
for k, v in hour_summation.items():
    print(k + ': ' + str(v) + ' hours')
```

Here's the result when I give an input:
fyi. Steve Miller is not in the csv file so that first response is correct. However, Sri Mantri is in the file and it should continue on and print out all the listings under her name.

```
Enter your full name: Steve Miller
Name is not in system
Enter your full name: Sri Mantri
Name is not in system
```

Here's what the output should look like when the code runs.

```
Enter your full name: Sri mantri
This is sri mantri full hours report:
Beeline Blank: 28 hours
SRV-0001 Service Requests for Base and Direct Services: 4 hours
SUP-0001 Support Requests with a CISM Ticket: 129 hours
SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support: 72 hours
0026184229 Margin Controlling Java Rewrite: 4 hours
0033472751 PRE-AFE 2017 - CMS Enhancements: 2 hours
0033472863 PRE-AFE 2017 - BPM Enhancements: 67 hours
APP-10008 Pre-Series (Non-Mainframe): 4 hours
APP-10146 Logistics (Non-Mainframe): 3 hours
APP-10195 Vehicle Labor System (Mainframe): 3 hours
APP-10354 Web PartsPro (Non-Mainframe): 1 hours
APP-10431 VIPService (Non-Mainframe): 1 hours
APP-10432 VIPService (Mainframe): 3 hours
APP-10536 Truck Invoice Adjustments (Mainframe): 2 hours
```

and the csv looks like this:

```
First Name  Last Name   Activity    Hours
Sri Mantri  SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  11
Sri Mantri  SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  3
Sri Mantri  SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  5
Sri Mantri  SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  2
Jeff    Moore   SUP-2503 Web Application Maintenance & Support  3
David   Ayers   SUP-2507  NAFTA MFTS OS Support 10
Prasanth    Musunuru    0020826809 Vertex 6.0 at the NDC    4
Prasanth    Musunuru    0020826809 Vertex 6.0 at the NDC    3
Prasanth    Musunuru    0020826809 Vertex 6.0 at the NDC    1
Prasanth    Musunuru    0020826809 Vertex 6.0 at the NDC    1
Jeff    Moore   0024480049 Fuel Tanks (infrastructure) - time tracking  1
Jeff    Moore   0024480049 Fuel Tanks (infrastructure) - time tracking  1
Jeff    Moore   0024480049 Fuel Tanks (infrastructure) - time tracking  4
```

Comment: The `while`-loop with the second `input` is inside the `for`-loop so it only looks at the currently processed `row`.

Comment: So do you think I should remove the for loop in general?

Comment: @stevenmiller Your csv file does not have any commas.

Comment: @Goyo, I wasn't really sure how to add a csv to the question so I just pulled it from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for input inside the while loop that never checks any row other then the current row. It looks like you're trying to iterate over the entire list to see if the name is anywhere in there (which is rough performance wise but I won't confuse you by getting into that xD) so your input check and loops need to be moved around a bit like so:

```
import csv

with open('Report1.csv') as csvfile:
  hour_summation = {}
  read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  name_found = False
  while not name_found:
    # take user input for name
    full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()
    # start search at top of file. Have to do this or each loop will
    # start at the end of the file after the first check.
    csvfile.seek(0)
    for row in read_csv:
      # check to see if row matches name
      if(' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() == full_name.strip().lower():
        name_found = True
        hour_summation[row[2]] = hour_summation.get(row[2], 0) + int(float(row[3]))

    # name wasn't found, so repeat process
    if not name_found:
      # name wasn't found, go back to start of while loop
      print('Name is not in system')
    else:
      # break out of while loop. Technically not required since while
      # will exit here anyway, but clarity is nice
      break

print('This is {} full hours report:'.format(full_name))
for k, v in hour_summation.items():
    print(k + ': ' + str(v) + ' hours')
```

Comment: This is really close to what I need however it only prints out the first line of the csv that is associated with the user name. I'm trying to get a full hours report from that name.

Comment: @stevenmiller Yeah i messed up. I just removed a line that wasn't supposed to be there. I had an extra break that was breaking the for loop too early. Check edit and try again. Should get you every row with that name.

Comment: You rocked it my man! This is exactly what I was looking for. Now if only I could make sure misspelled names could be avoided. lol

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()
bucle = True
with open('Report1.csv') as csvfile:
    hour_summation = {}
    read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    while bucle:    
        for row in read_csv:
            if(' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() == full_name.strip().lower():
                hour_summation[row[2]] = hour_summation.get(row[2], 0) + int(float(row[3]))
                bucle = False
        if bucle:
            print('Name is not in system')
            full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()
            csvfile.seek(0)

print('This is {} full hours report:'.format(full_name))
for k, v in hour_summation.items():
print(k + ': ' + str(v) + ' hours')
```

Comment: This won't work without seeking the file back to the top. `csv.reader` doesn't return a list or something that can just be reiterated over again and again.

Comment: It works now but only 1x through the loop and then errors out.

Comment: he's seeking the wrong thing. you have to seek the file, not the reader which is what my answer does.

Comment: Ok, my fault. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the file can have multiple lines related to the given full name, try something like:

```
import csv

full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower()
run=1
while run:    
    with open('Report1.csv') as csvfile:
        hour_summation = {}
        read_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in read_csv:
            if(' '.join((row[0], row[1]))).lower() == full_name.strip().lower():
                hour_summation[row[2]] = hour_summation.get(row[2], 0) + int(float(row[3]))

    if hour_summation:
        print('This is {} full hours report:'.format(full_name))
        for k, v in hour_summation.items():
            print(k + ': ' + str(v) + ' hours')
        run=0
    else:
        print('Name is not in system')
        full_name = input('Enter your full name: ').lower() # following your code, 
                                                            # request for a new full name comes only in case no results for the 1st one
```

Comment: This works great except the loop is only good for one error. So when I input two names in a row which are not in the csv it only works 1 time and then stops.

Comment: I've added upper loop, so it'll ask for the name till it get a valid one, thereafter it'll stop. The logic and the code can be different depending on the requirements